# Trying to dynamically create a modal and execute custom script fails

Tags: jquery, asp.net, modal-dialog

Firstly, When i append my Data and Code into the wrapper, it doesnt show the code which is very peculiar. when i quick watch this with Visual Studios.  Then finally it wont show the modal at all.

Code:

```
var wrapper = $("<div>");
var data = $("<select>");
data.append('<option value = "17">Asset Name Read Only</option>').append('<option value = "18">Asset Type</option>').append('<option value = "19">Asset Code Read Only</option>').append('<option value = "20">Asset Parent</option>').append('<option value = "21">Asset Parent All</option>').append('<option value = "22">Asset Name Editable</option>').append('<option value = "23">Asset Code Editable</option>')
var code = $("<script>").attr("type", "text/javascript").html('$(".modal select option").click(function(){$(SELECTED_ELEMENT).attr("elType", $(this).val());});');
wrapper.append(data).append(code);
parent.showOverlay();
parent.showModal(wrapper);
```

the above statement "parent.showModal(wrapper)" is as follows:

```
function showModal(data){
  $("<div class = 'modal'>").css({
      top: $(window).height() / 2 - $("div.modal").height() / 2,
      left: $(window).width() / 2 - $("div.modal").width() / 2
  }).append(data).fadeIn();
}
```

Im not quite sure what is going on in the sense that neither the modal is showing nor why the javascript is being appended to the wrapper div.  What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no appendTo("body") which is needed to show it.

As for the script, dont send the script to the function, but just the HTML since it works, then after the line be like:

parent.showModal(wrapper);
wrapper.find("option").click(function(){
   //insert code here
});

Answer (score 0):

You should make it using plugin, here is simple code

```
(function($){
    $.fn.modal = function(){
      //append div to body
     $("<div />").appendTo('body').attr("id","modal").css({width: 200, height:120, background-color:'red', position:'absolute', display:'none'});
    win_width = $(window).width(); //get the width of window
    win_height = $(window).height();
    mod_width = $('#modal').width();
    mod_height = $('#modal').height();
    //calculate values to center the modal
    m_top = (win_height / 2) - (mod_height / 2);
    m_left = (win_width / 2) - (mod_width / 2);
    //center modal
    $("#modal").css({top: m_top, left: m_left});
    $("#modal").fadeIn();
    }
})(jQuery);
```

please make sure to call it.

```
<button id = 'button'>CLick me</button> // html button
$('#button').modal(); // call plugin in js
```

Comment: I was trying this with jsfiddle.net to see if i could get it working.  Can you make a demo with it?  Im trying to adjust your code, though i do like where you are headed